# Adding local/global variables using module in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sympy

I'm working with the Sympy module to build a class that can be used for deriving certain equations symbolically, and I'm running into issue with how the module behaves in the Jupyter notebook environment.  Here is a simple snippet of code that gets to the crux of the issue:

I import sympy and define the following class in a Jupyter notebook:

```
from sympy import *

class example:

    def __init__(self, parameters):
        self.y = simplify(0)
        globals().update(dict((p, symbols(p)) for p in parameters))

    def define_expression(self, expression1):
        self.y = expression1

    def add_expression(self, expression2):
        return self.y + expression2
```

If run this in a Jupyter notebook, then I can complete the following operations without any issues:

```
temp = example(['x'])
temp.define_expression(x+1)
temp.add_expression(x**2+1)
```

On the other hand, if I save the code above as test_class.py and run the following code in a Jupyter notebook

```
import test_class as tc

temp = tc.example(['x'])
temp.define_expression('x+1')
```

then I get the following error:

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-e7d0340f038c> in <module>()
----> 1 temp.define_expression(x+1)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

My question is boils down to the following: Can one create a class that defines Sympy symbols that can be used globally in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: I did find a work around, but it is a bit annoying.  Instead of typing               "temp.define_expression(x+1)"            
I could type            "temp.define_expression(tc.x+1)"